# Could a mass of osmium be used to create a 0g room on Earth?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Is it possible for a super dense element (such as osmium) to cancel out earth's gravitational field, and create a room without gravitational acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

No. You would need an object with a mass equal to the mass of Earth to be placed on the ceiling.

Comment: Not quite.  If the density of the roof was much higher then you would be nearer its centre of mass and hence you could get the same attraction from a smaller mass.  However, even with osmium, you would still need a ridiculous amount.

Comment: A quick Google and some mental arithmetic gives me an estimate that a sphere of osmium just half the radius of the Earth should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, using a high density substance we don't need to equal the Earth's mass, but using osmium doesn't help that much. If we could get degenerate matter like neutronium, the mass could be much smaller than Earth's, but of course neutronium isn't stable in small quantities, and even if it were stable it would be difficult to use as a construction material. ;)

Comment: actually if the height of the ceiling is just 1000 closer than the center of earth, then a millionth of the mass of earth should suffice. So basically the mass of a small asteroid, but in order to enhance the 0g region you would need to consider careful arrangements of masses to cancel as many multipolar moments as possible

Comment: @badjohn I think it would be half that size. The mean density of Earth is $5.51 g/cm^3$, a little under 1/4 the density of osmium. And surface gravity $g\propto r\rho$. So a sphere with 1/4 the radius of the Earth should suffice. Obtaining that much osmium may require ransacking several stellar systems. :)

Comment: Yes.  I Googled a bit too quickly and I got the density of the inner core.  A precise answer might not match yours or mine but is probably closer to yours.  I think that we can agree that it is a totally ridiculous amount of osmium.

Comment: Might be more feasible to burrow down to the center of the earth and line the hole with whatever material you were going to use to hold up that osmium ball.  Plus some insulation from the same vendor, of course.